# I got checkstyle warning: WhitespaceAround: WhitespaceAround: '{' is not preceded with whitespace

Tags: java, spring-boot, compiler-warnings, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

When I build my project, So I got this checkstyle warning : WhitespaceAround: WhitespaceAround: '{' is not preceded with whitespace. Can you please help me to remove this warning.

```
public List<ObjectSyncStatus> createEntities(Long connectorId, EntityRequest entityRequest) {
    if (connectorId == null && entityRequest == null){
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    String entitiesUrl = connectorEndpoint + CONNECTOR_PATH + connectorId + "/entities";
    HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.POST;

    HttpEntity<EntityRequest> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(entityRequest);
    ResponseEntity<List> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(entitiesUrl, method, httpEntity, List.class);
    log.info(OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL, responseEntity);

    return mapper.mapAsList(responseEntity.getBody(), ObjectSyncStatus.class);
}
```

I got the warning in If condition.

Comment: Well, the warning message exactly tells you what's wrong: you have a `{` which is not preceded with a whitespace. On the second line of your code, replace `){` with `) {`.

Comment: sorry but this is obvious, why posting it here?

Answer (score 4):

The Checkstyle configuration that you are using expects the `{` to have a space before it. Your code looks like this at the moment:

```java
if (connectorId == null && entityRequest == null){
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Checkstyle wants it to look like this:

```java
if (connectorId == null && entityRequest == null) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```